# SwiftUI button hittable outside image?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a button in SwiftUI (macOS) defined like this:

```
      Button(action: { print("hit") },
             label: { Image(systemName: "minus") })
        .frame(width: 21, height: 21)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
```

When I select the button in the preview, the green highlight rectangle shows the expected square shape for the button. But only the image itself is actually clickable, and that minus sign is hard to hit. I thought `.contentShape(Rectangle())` would fix that, but it doesn't seem to have any effect, either before or after `.frame()`.

How do I make the button's entire frame area clickable?

Comment: I can't reproduce this — have you tried running the code you posted in a clean project?

Comment: It looks like the thing I was missing was `.buttonStyle(.plain)` (it was on a parent view). I made sure I can replicate it in a clean project (note that the issue doesn't happen in a Playground).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of set external frame (which adds space "around" button), move it inside, to content, which will "increase" the button, like

```
  Button(action: { print("hit") },
         label: { 
           Image(systemName: "minus") 
              .frame(width: 21, height: 21)    // << here !!
              .contentShape(Rectangle())       // << add this !!
         })
    .buttonStyle(.plain)
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.4

Comment: simply, the trick is adding contentShape after the frame. contentShape by itself does not help.